# What API does Safari use for the account password

Tags: macos, security, authentication, safari, passwords

Here is a dialog box to request the user's macOS account password:

[image]

Which API is Safari using employing to make use of this password? Can I use the same APIs in my own app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Activity Monitor to see which files Safari has open. It seems that the framework you are looking for is:

```
 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LocalAuthenticationUI.framework/
```

There is a public [LocalAuthentication framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/), but the UI part used by Safari seems private.

According to this [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html):

> Private frameworks are appropriate for code modules you want to use in your own applications but do not want other developers to use.